# A question on compact space satisfying open (G)

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ satisfies open (G) if for each $x \in X$ we have a
countable open neighborhood base $\mathcal B_x$ of $x$ such that
whenever $x \in \overline{A}$ and $N(x)$ is a neighborhood of $x$,
then for some $a \in A$ we have $x \in B \subset N(x)$ for some $B
\in \mathcal B_a$.

How could I prove that a compact space $X$ satisfying open (G) is metrisable?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is this definition coming from? I have seen a few sources on "open (G)" where it is defined differently (and I haven't yet figured out if your formulation is equivalent).

Comment: Probably some separation axiom is implied here, because otherwise $X$ indiscrete will trivially satisfy open (G) I think.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the space $X$ is Hausdorff. It is clear, that $X$ is metrizable iff $X$ is separable. But this not always holds. A simple (but a unique) counterexample which I found is [Concentric Circles]( https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000095.

Comment: I don't understand: your claim is that "open (G)" + Hausdorff + separable implies second countable?

Comment: And you claim that the Aleksandrov double of the circle is "open (G)"?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes. For the first let $A$ be a countable dense subset of the space $X$. Then $\bigcup_{a\in A}\mathcal B_a$ is a countable base for $X$. For the second I have the following idea. Consider both $C_1$ and $C_2$ as the standard unit circle $\Bbb T=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$. For each $a\in C_1$ let $\mathcal B_a=\{B_{1/n}(a):n\in\omega\}$, where $B_{1/n}(a)=\{x\in C_1:|x-a|<1/n\}$.  For each $a\in C_2$ let $\mathcal B_a=\{a\}\cup\{B’_{1/n}(a):n\in\omega\}$, where $B’_{1/n}(a)=\{a\}\cup\{x\in C_1:|x-a|<1/n\}$.

Comment: But the concentric circles are not separable?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes. This is why it is a counterexample.

Comment: Your construction would show that the CC obey "decreasing open (G)", and any $T_1$ space that satisfies that is metrisable (Collins-Roscoe theorem). So either the condition of the OP is not classical open (G), or your argument for CC being open (G) is wrong, I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I googled a paper by [Collins, Reed, Roscoe and Rudin](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-094-03/S0002-9939-1985-0787900-X/S0002-9939-1985-0787900-X.pdf). It seems that the bases $\mathcal B_a$ which I proposed for CC should witness it has open (G) with respect to its definition from this paper (provided we understand it as $\exists s\forall y\dots$), but them cannot be enumerated to witness that CC has  *decreasing* open (G), because for each point $a\in C_2$ the family  $\mathcal B_a$ contains a singleton.

Comment: I thought going from their earlier paper as well, that the $s$ does vary with $y$. And I don't see how your construction is not decreasing. See page 488, top, about the dependence of $s$ on $y$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma OK. But if we allow for each $y$ its own $s$ then this condition will be even weaker, so CC should have open (G). It seems the following. My construction cannot be reenumerated (or even modified) to be decreasing. Indeed, each point $a\in C_2$ is isolated, so a base $\mathcal B_a=\{W(n,a)\}$ at $a$ should contain a singleton $\{a\}$. So $W(n(a),a)=\{a\}$ for some number $n(a)$. If the family $\mathcal B_a$ is decreasing then $W(n,a)=\{a\}$ for all $n\ge n(a)$. So the family  $\mathcal B_a$ contains only finitely many neighborhoods intersecting with $C_1$.

Comment: Thus there exists a natural number $m(a)$ such that each neighborhood $W\in\mathcal B(a)$ intersecting with $C_1$ contains an arc of the circle $C_1$ of length $1/m(a)$. For each $m$ put $C(m)=\{a\in C_2:m(a)=m\}$. Since the space $\Bbb T$ is Baire, there exists a number $m$ such that the set $C(m)$ is dense in a non-empty open set $Y\subset\Bbb T$. If we take any point  $x\in C_1$ of $Y$ and consider its neighborhood $U$ which is an arc of length less than $1/m$, we should easily obtain a contradiction with open (G).

Comment: So you have shown that CC does not have open (G). I kind of follow the rough argument , haven't checked all the details. So it's no longer a counterexample to the OP's question? Have you checked whether OP's open (G) is equivalent to the "real" open (G) from the mentioned paper?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No. My arguments suggest the following. CC has both OP open (G) and “real”  open (G), so it is a counterexample to the OP's question. But it fails to have a decreasing “real”  open (G), so it is not a counterexample to Collins-Roscoe metrization theorem.

Comment: I did not check whether OP's open (G) is equivalent to the "real" open (G).